# Enter key and firefox hints

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an irritating problem with submitting form on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

In my form <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is bound to javascript method that submits it (override is caused by using styled links instead of submit buttons). 
Now when user begins to write his username in one of the fields he gets browser suggestions for autofill. It's cool, but choosing one of them requires pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, which submits the form before the choice.

Is there any way to detect the hint window of the browser?

The problem does not occur in chrome.

Comment: Can you give a fiddle???

Comment: I cannot, the code is kind of complicated, its a part of a big project.

Answer (score 1):

Add `return false;` before the function call in your `onkeydown`. I had a very similar problem not long back. E.g.

`<input type="text" onkeydown="return event.keyCode!=13; someFunction()" />`

Comment: How would it help? Submitting occurs before the return statement.
<code>
function(){
if (enter was pressed)
    form.submit();
}
return false;
</code>